# c++ Thread not terminating at end of function

Tags: c++, multithreading, stack, queue

I am new to C++ and threading. I have an assignment where we are supposed to create a multithreaded version of the sieve of eartosthenes algorithm to find prime numbers. We were instructed to use a thread safe queue to accomplish this. The main thread is supposed to created an unbounded sequence of numbers from 2 - infinity. The main thread will also create a filter thread. This filter thread reads from queue q0 and puts all of the numbers that aren't a multiple of N into another queue (q1). Q1 will get passed to another thread that will also filter out numbers and place them into another queue. This goes on and on until it finds the right amount of prime numbers and then the program terminates. Or at least it should. For some reason there is a problem in the last thread. It doesn't terminate at the end of the function. It jumps around randomly in the function. Using gdb it kept telling me the thread cannot find bounds of current function. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. I think it could have to do with something messing up my stack?

```
void filtering(safeQueue& q1, bool& running, int& userNum, int& primes){
    safeQueue q2;
    int num;
    int popped;

    q1.pop(num);

    cout<< "Prime is found: "<<num <<endl;
    primes++;

    if(primes >= userNum){
        running = false;
        return;
    }

    q1.pop(popped);
    if((popped%num)!= 0)
        q2.push(popped);
    if(running){
        thread filter(filtering, ref(q2), ref(running), ref(userNum), ref(primes));

        while(running){
            q1.pop(popped);
            if((popped%num)!=0)
                q2.push(popped);
        }
        filter.join();
        return;
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int num;
    int i = 3;
    safeQueue q0;
    bool running = true;
    int primes = 0;
    int userNum = 0;

userNum = getInput();
q0.push(2);

    thread filter2(filtering, ref(q0), ref(running), ref(userNum), ref(primes));

    while(running){
        q0.push(i);
        i++;
    }
    filter2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my safeQueue class (cpp)

```
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include "safeQueue.hpp"

using namespace std;
void safeQueue::pop(int& data)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu);
    while(q.empty())
    {
        conVar.wait(lock);
    }
    data = q.front();
    q.pop();
}
void safeQueue::push(const int& data)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu);
    q.push(data);
    lock.unlock();
    conVar.notify_one();
}
```

safeQueue (header)

```
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class safeQueue
{
public:
    void pop(int& data);

    void push(const int& data);

private:
    queue<int> q;
    mutable mutex mu;
    condition_variable conVar;
};
```

This program has to run without memory leaks as well. If I could properly get the threads to close then I'm positive I won't have to worry about memory leaks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you recursively creating threads? Threads that will not work in parallel because you wait for the threads to finish before continuing.

Comment: You have no protection of either `running` or `primes`. (And why is `userNum` a reference?)

Comment: As a side note, The True Sieve of Eratosthenes doesn't test for divisibility.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is as it should be. They do work in parallel, as the `join` is after the `while(running)` loop.